# Firefox ignoring user.js from command line created profile

Tags: firefox

I'm trying to load the custom preferences into Firefox from a c# program. I'm creating a new firefox profile by running

```
firefox.exe -CreateProfile profileName
```

I'm then creating a user.js file inside the new profile folder created and writing the following options to it

```
user_pref("network.proxy.http", "IP_HERE")
user_pref("network.proxy.http_port", 80);
user_pref("network.proxy.type", 1);
```

I then launch with

```
firefox.exe -P profileName
```

However it just seems to ignore the user.js file completely. Both Firefox instances are launched with System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm running into this as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences says "Note: because of abuse of user.js preferences, support for user.js may be removed in a future version of Firefox." but I haven't found concrete information whether it actually was already removed or not.

Comment: Weird, after a bit of playing around I got it working and can't reproduce the problem even by undoing the the changes. `user.js` is loaded just fine.